# Passing data from parent to child (Nested Form)

Tags: javascript, angular, input, angular2-forms

I'm creating a nested form in which I have the parent component that holds the form(s) and has the submit button. And there's the child component which is the form itself.

When I submit the form the property `submitted` became `true`, I need to inform my child component that `submitted` is now `true` when submitted.

This is the code from submit button in parent component:

```
      enviarDados(model: dadosAcordo, isValid: boolean, isJuridica:boolean) {
        this.servError = "";
        this.submitted = true; 
        //more code
       }
```

And this is how the child component look like so far:

```
export class TitularComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input('group') // this is the input for the form
  @Input('submitted') // input for the status of submit
  public titularForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter();


  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private finalizaAcordo:FinalizaNegociacaoService) {} 

  ngOnChanges(){

  }
// more code
```

This is the html on the parent component:

```
<div class="wrap-acordo">
  <form [formGroup]="formDadosBancarios" novalidate class="" (ngSubmit)="enviarDados(formDadosBancarios.value)">
      <div formArrayName="dados_titular">
        <div *ngFor="let dados_titular of formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="col s12" *ngIf="formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.length > 1">
              <span class="span-removeTitular right-align" (click)="removeTitular(i)"> Remover {{i+1}}º Titular </span>
            </div>
            <titular (modelChanged)="recebeValidators($event)" [group]="formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.controls[i]"></titular>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <input type="submit" class="botao-medio btn-aceita" value="Aceitar">
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <input type="button" class="botao-medio btn-recusa" value="Recusar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: use `@Input()` ! Yes, we need some code....

Comment: Now it has some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component, when the button is clicked, set this.formsubmitted = true . And in child cmponent set this form submitted as input using @Input. If you need to dp something once the formsubmitted becomes true, use ngonchanges for the input formsubmitted.
Ngonchanges(change: Simplechange) {
if(changes['submitted']&& changes['submitted'].currentvalue){
Do your stuff here
}
}

You can refer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've editted the question with some code, can you help me? How will the child know that the form is submitted just with the input?

Comment: When the input value to child changes ie submitted here, the change can be detected by using ngonchanges as in the code above

Comment: Thanks RemyaJ, but should'nt I do something in the html? Something like `<titular [submitted]="something here"> </titular>`.

Comment: Yes. <titular [submitted]="submitted"> the submitted in square brackets is your input to child and its value is the second submitted ie its value in parent component.

Comment: Right! thats it. Thank you very much for you patience, it helped me a lot. :)